# booktabs with custom column spacing

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'm trying to use the `booktabs` package, and I'm trying to make tables with "column groups" that are delimited by extra space. In the following, I am doing this using the `@{}` syntax in the `tabular` environment header. Unfortunately, however, this seems to ruin the alignment of the `multicolumns` and the `cmidrules`. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{cc @{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}
    *{2}{c} @{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}
    *{2}{c} @{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}
    *{2}{c} }
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{C}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
  & D & E & F & E & F & E & F\\
  \midrule
  G    & 4.6 & 1.7 & 0.35 & 0.30 & 0.5 & 0.21 & 0.24\\
  H    & 6.5 & 2.7 & 1.4  & 1.2  & 1.3  & 0.30 & 5\\
  I    & 8.7 & 7.3 & 4.6  & 8.5  & 89.3  & 3.7  & 2\\
  J    & 1.4  & 13  & 9.7  & 13   & 8.7  & 8.2   & 4\\
  K    & 5 & 2  & 85   & 18   & 74   & 2.9   & 0.24\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: rather than altering the column width, I could also use phantom columns, but they seem a little wide and I run into the same problem of adjusting individual column widths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things help, in conjunction:

1. Adjusting the header of `\multicolumn`s to `@{}c@{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}` --- this deals with the alignment
2. Adjusting the right trim of `\cmidline`: `(lr{\dimexpr 4\tabcolsep+0.5em})` --- this deals with line lengths

The full code of the upper part of the table is thus:

```
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\hskip 4\tabcolsep}}{B} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{C}\\
  \cmidrule(lr{\dimexpr 4\tabcolsep+0.5em}){3-4} \cmidrule(lr{\dimexpr 4\tabcolsep+0.5em}){5-6}
\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
  & D & E & F & E & F & E & F\\
  \midrule
```

I suspect you will want to further tweak the line lenghts and/or use decimal point alignment...

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm! You are right, though, I needed to tweak the lines a bit. Decimal point alignment would be nice, would this cause problems in the alignment?

Comment: Glad to hear this! ---I don't think it would.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132192/23948), you should never use `\hskip` in LaTeX code. Use `\hspace{4\tabcolsep}` here.