# When should you use \vskip (\hskip) rather than \vspace (\hspace) in a LaTeX document?

Tags: spacing, macros

I assume that, to guard against strange errors, you should use `\vspace` rather than `\vskip` whenever possible in a LaTeX document. But are there any situations in which you must use `\vskip`?

I'm wondering the same thing about `\hspace` vs. `\hskip`.

Comment: This one is easy: never. `;-)`

Comment: IMO if you use LaTeX semantically (for writing a document, as opposed to designing it), you should use neither skips nor spaces.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The answer is easy: you should never use `\vskip` in a LaTeX document. The only precaution to be taken is adding a blank line before `\vspace` when the vertical space is meant to appear *between* paragraphs, which usually is the case.

However, `\vspace` can also appear in a paragraph and the vertical spacing will be applied below the text line where the command finally happens to fall: think of it as an invisible “word” that extends below the baseline (but this space will disappear at a page break anyway).

There are several reasons for not using `\vskip` (except, maybe, in basic LaTeX programming):

1. it's easy to add a * where needed;
2. it's easy to change `\vspace` into `\addvspace` (when two consecutive `\addvspace` commands, that are usually issued by macros rather than directly, only the largest one prevails);
3. the syntax conforms to the traditional LaTeX one *and* a `\relax` is placed by default behind the scenes, thus avoiding some possible problems that, by Murphy's law, will show as very weird errors.

Similarly, never use `\hskip` in a LaTeX document, but prefer `\hspace` which avoids head scratching in cases such as

```
text\hskip 1pt plus other text
```

Try it. `;-)` Then you'll switch to

```
text\hspace{1pt}plus other text
```

Notice that `\hspace{...}` should not be preceded nor followed by a space, because we're overriding TeX's rules at that point and we probably don't want other spaces to begin with.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying it's okay to use \vskip in macros or in a package?

Comment: @GeoffPointer If the author knows what they're doing, yes, why not? `\vskip` and `\vspace` have quite distinctive features (the former adds `\par` if not in vertical mode).

Comment: There's no why not. I just wanted to be sure the distinction was being made.

Answer (score 6):

If you are an author of the text, you should never use `\vspace` nor `\vskip` because you should use only logical markup of the document. And typographical issue is responsibility of used macros.

If you are macro programmer then you like TeX primitives like `\vskip`, `\vadjust`, `\hskip` because you understand well what they are doing. And you needn't to use a complicated macros like `\vspace` in your macros.

The result: there is no need to use `\vspace`.

Moreover, `\vspace` is a big source of user confusions, because its default behaviour is something like `\vadjust{\vskip...}` so, it breaks line grid in the current paragraph but it doesn't end the paragraph.

Comment: I respect your optimism, but usually we are both the author of the text and responsible for its typography. ;)

Answer (score 3):

One difference that appears strange to me is, that `\hspace` does not eat following spaces:

```
Test\hskip0.1\textwidth\relax Test

Test\hspace{0.1\textwidth} Test

Test\hspace{0.1\textwidth}Test
```

Thus, in many low level cases `\hskip` is preferred. This appeared to me when implementing something similar to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33979/include-a-line-break-in-algorithmic-while-maintaining-indentation).

Comment: There is *no* following space to be eaten up in the first case: a space after a control sequence is always ignored during tokenization, so it simply doesn't enter in TeX processing. A better example could be `Test\hskip 1pt test` where a space is actually eaten up, but just because a space token is always ignored after a unit of measure (when a length is required by the syntax rules).