# Help designing a Title Page for thesis

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I'm having trouble getting my title page to look just right. Few questions:

1. How can I along the text such that it doesn't shift?
2. I don't want to make use of absolute coordinates (i.e. I had yshift=-15cm before, but it got really complicated to style the whole page at once).
3. Is the approach I'm taking the best? Maybe there is a better way.

Here is what I need it to look like (without the top two lines, of course):
[image]

but here is what I got:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
% Title Page Variables
\title{Mining Partially Ordered Sequential Rules on Unbounded Data}
\author{Andriy Drozdyuk}
\def\previousDegrees{Bachelor of Computer Science, University of Toronto, 2001}
\def\subtitleTemplate{A Thesis Submitted in Partial Fulfillment
       of the Requirements for the Degree of}
\def\degree{Masters of Computer Science}
\def\gau{Computer Science}
\def\supervisorMain{Michael W. Fleming, Ph.D., Professor, Faculty of Computer Science}
\def\supervisor{Scott Buffett, Ph.D., Adjunct Professor, Faculty of Computer Science}

\def\board{Name, Degree, Department, Chair}
\def\examiner{Name, Degree, Department/Field, Institution PhD Only}
\def\submissionDate{January, 2017}
\def\gradYear{2017}
\def\unb{\MakeUppercase{The University of New Brunswick}}
% Title Page Sizes
\def\mytitlewidth{12cm}

% Title Page Layout

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
  % Remember where the picture is relative to the page
  % Overlay keeps the bounding box under control - prevents growing
  % to encompass the referenced points (e.g. current page)
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \node[yshift=-6cm] at (current page.north) (title) [text width=\mytitlewidth, align=center]{\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\@title}};
    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (title) (by) [text width=\mytitlewidth, align=center]{by};
    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (by) (author) {\Large\@author};

    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (author) (previousDegrees) {\previousDegrees};

    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (previousDegrees) (subtitle) {\subtitleTemplate};

    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (subtitle) (degree) {\degree};

    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (degree) (gau) {in the Graduate Academic Unit of \gau};

    \node[right,yshift=-1cm] at (gau) (supervisors) {Supervisors:};

    \node[right, xshift=4cm, align=left] at (supervisors) {\supervisorMain};
    \node[right, xshift=4cm, yshift=-1cm,align=left] at (supervisors) {\supervisor};

    \node[right,yshift=-2cm] at (supervisors) (examBoard) {Examining Board:};
    \node[right,xshift=4cm] at (examBoard) {\board};

    \node[right,yshift=-2cm] at (examBoard) (externalExaminer) {External Examiner:};
    \node[right,xshift=4cm] at (examBoard) {\examiner};

    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (externalExaminer) (acceptedBy) {This thesis is accepted by the};
    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (acceptedBy) (dean) {Dean of Graduate Studies};

    \node[yshift=-2cm] at (dean) (unb) {\unb};

    \node[yshift=-2cm] at (unb) (submissionDate) {\submissionDate};

    \copyright\node[yshift=-2cm] at (submissionDate) (authorYear) {\@author, \gradYear};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{titlepage}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to require using a `tikzpicture` at all, does it?

Comment: @AboAmmar No, but I wanted to get the layout to match exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with something as simple as this (pay attention to the actual requirements of your institution):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

{\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont%
MINING PARTIALLY ORDERED SEQUENTIAL RULES\\ ON UNBOUNDED DATA\par
}

\vskip2\baselineskip
by

\vskip2\baselineskip
Andriy Drozdyuk\par
Bachelor of Computer Science, University of Toronto, 2001

\vskip2\baselineskip
A Thesis Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of\\ the Requirements for the Degree of

\vskip2\baselineskip
Masters of Computer Science

\vskip2\baselineskip
in the Graduate Academic Unit of Computer Science

\vfill
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Supervisors: & Michael W. Fleming, Ph.D., Professor, Faculty of Computer Science\\
             & Scott Buffett, Ph.D., Adjunct Professor, Faculty of Computer Science\\
             &                                    \\
Examining Board: & Name, Degree, Department, Chair\\
             &                                    \\
External Examiner: & Department/Field, Institution PhD Only             
\end{tabular}


\vfill
This thesis is accepted by the\\
Dean of Graduate Studies

\vskip2\baselineskip
THE UNIVERSITY OF NEW BRUNSWICK\par
January, 2017

\vskip2\baselineskip
\copyright\ Andriy Drozdyuk, 2017

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

You get this:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the same as the one provided (which is actually the requirement from my institution). I want to get _exactly_ the same positioning, hence the reason I used tikz. E.g.  Supervisors should be aligned left.

Comment: @drozzy  -- I edited my answer to get it more close to the image you posted. As I said, It is just a start. There is no such __exact__ thing between MS Word and LaTeX documents. The original template for your image is prepared using MS Word at 12pt.  In my opinion, the LaTeX version is much better.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. How did you know that you needed to do `\vskip2`? Is it just trial and error?

Comment: Also, what do the packages newtxtext and geometry do? I mean which commands do they provide here?

Comment: Seems like this answer cautions _against_ using `vskip` in a document: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126200/when-should-you-use-vskip-hskip-rather-than-vspace-hspace-in-a-latex-doc I'm not not really sure what `vskip` does or how it works.

Comment: @drozzy - `\vskip2\baselineskip` is approx. equal to two `Enter`s in Word. `\vskip` is a low-level TeX command and there is no harm using it in such a limited scope as a `titlepage`, because it has no other macros or environments which can spoil it. So, if you really know what you do, go ahead and use it. Otherwise, `\vspace{2\baselineskip}` will be safer. The `newtxtext` package sets the rm font to `Times Roman`, a clone of Word's `Times New Roman`. If your document contains also some math, then adding `newtxmath` will be a perfect match. `geometry` sets all the margins to `1in = 2.54cm`.